# How to get a working QR code scanner for Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I’m kind of expecting the impossible, but asking anyway to ensure I’ve not missed out on any great ideas.

I’ve tried a couple of Flutter QR code scanner libraries, but as I was kind of expecting, none of those would run when I used the web beta support in Chrome for instance.

My question is, is there a Flutter QR code scanner library that works for iOS, Android and Web?

If not, is there a way to write this in Flutter for Web specifically?

There was one Stack Overflow question of running a QR scanner JavaScript library inside a WebView and trying to run a Web version which the post indicated faced issues with camera streaming. Is this a possible approach that would translate to Web?

Is there any other way to have a QR code scanner in Flutter to run in Web?

Comment: Any updates with your research?

Comment: running the qr code scanner on flutter web yields an error message "Unknown error: unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem"

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter/the-power-of-webviews-in-flutter-a56234b57df2   If you have a qr code reader in javascript then webviews may be a solution

Comment: I tried ChromeSafariBrowser and it threw a similar error

Comment: https://gitmemory.com/issue/flutter/flutter/46662/563937930   (the flutter team says it webview is not currently supported in chrome web)  I wish they would move all the platforms together before releasing.

Comment: Did you try using a JS library? There is no need to use a web view in Flutter web as the Dart code is transpiled to JS, so you can simply directly use any JS API.

Comment: What about Firebase ML Scanner ?

Comment: see this package https://pub.dev/packages/ai_barcode

Answer (score 1):

You could use an API like http://goqr.me/api/ in your flutter web project. You just have to use the `read command` on their api. I think it returns a response in either json or xml. If that isn't enough there are othe apis just search it till you find a cool one